# Should be used a CoroutineScope's extension function or a suspending function

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm writing an app using coroutines (code below is greatly simplified). Recently I've watched [Coroutines in Practice](https://youtu.be/a3agLJQ6vt8?t=2195) talk and got a little confused. Turns out I don't know when to use a `CoroutineScope`'s extension function and when to use a suspending function.

I have a **mediator** (Presenter/ViewModel/Controller/etc) that implements CoroutineScope:

```
class UiMediator : CoroutineScope {
    private val lifecycleJob: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = lifecycleJob + CoroutineDispatchersProvider.MAIN
    // cancel parent Job somewhere

    fun getChannel() {
        launch {
            val channel = useCase.execute()
            view.show(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

**Business logic** (Interactor/UseCase):

```
class UseCase {
    suspend fun execute(): RssChannel = repository.getRssChannel()
}
```

And a **repository**:

```
class Repository {
    suspend fun getRssChannel(): RssChannel {
        // `getAllChannels` is a suspending fun that uses `withContext(IO)`
        val channels = localStore.getAllChannels()
        if (channels.isNotEmpty()) {
            return channels[0]
        }

        // `fetchChannel` is a suspending fun that uses `suspendCancellableCoroutine`
        // `saveChannel` is a suspending fun that uses `withContext(IO)`
        return remoteStore.fetchChannel()
            .also { localStore.saveChannel(it) }
    }
}
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Should I declare `Repository#getRssChannel` as a CoroutineScope's extension function (because
   it spawns new suspending functions: `getAllChannels`,
   `fetchChannel`, `saveChannel`)? How can I use it in the `UseCase` then?
2. Should I just wrap a `Repository#getRssChannel` into a
   `coroutineScope` function in order to make all spawned suspending
   functions to be children of the latter?
3. Or maybe it's already fine and I should change nothing. When to
   declare  a function as a `CoroutineScope`'s extension then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

No, you should **not** declare `Repository#getRssChannel` as an extension function of `CoroutineScope`, because you only invoke suspend functions but not start (`launch`/ `async`) new jobs. As @Francesc explained extension function of `CoroutineScope` should only start new jobs, but cannot return immediatly result and should not be declared as `suspend` by itself.

Answer to question 2:

No, you should **not** wrap `Repository#getRssChannel` into a `CoroutineScope`. Wrapping makes only sense if you start (`launch`/ `async`) new coroutines in this method. The new jobs would be children of the current job and the outer method will only return after all parallel jobs are finished. In your case you have sequential invocations of other suspending coroutines and there is no need of a new scope.

Answer to question 3:

Yes, you can stay with your code. If you would need the functionality of `UiMediator#getChannel` more then once, then this method would be a candidate of an extension function for `CoroutineScope`.

Answer (score 5):

A suspending function should return once it has completed its task, it executes something, possibly taking some time while not blocking the UI, and when it's done it returns.

A CoroutineScope extension function is for a fire-and-forget scenario, you call it, it spawns a coroutine and returns immediately, while the task continues to execute.

Comment: I'm still confused. In my code I usually have either code that I need to run synchronously like in your first example, or code that I need to run asynchronously (and concurrently!) then do something with the results, so fire-with-deferred-return-value? I almost never need fire-and-forget. So what do I use for fire-with-deferred-return-value?